# Webstorm Getters/Setter

Tags: javascript, getter, setter, typescript, webstorm

Здравствуйте. Я разрабатываю на Typescript в Webstorm и столкнулся с тем, что мне не совсем нравится код getter/setter, которые автоматически генерируются.

Нашёл способ, как это изменить в PHPStorm, но почему-то нигде не написано, как это сделать в Webstorm. Подскажите, есть ли возможность исправить шаблон, который за это отвечает?

Comment: Из вашего вопроса непонятно чего вы хотите добиться. Добавьте к вопросу: код который генерится, картинку или гифку, которые помогут описать поведение *WebStorm* которое вам не нравится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, для создания getter/setter в WebStorm не используются редактируемые шаблоны - генерация getters/setters зашита в коде. Можно изменить только префиксы, используемые при генерации - `Settings/Editor/Code Style/Typescript`, `Other/Naming conventions`